# Bootstrap 4 Split Navbar - Responsive Dropdown Below not Beside

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with a split dropdown. The particular portion of the HTML I'm interested in is this:

```
         <li class="nav-item">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <a href="http://www.bhastings.com/blog" target="_blank" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="dropdownMenuLink_blog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown for Blog Links</span>
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink_blog">
                      <div class="dropdown-header">Categories | <a href="http://bhastings.com/blog" target="_blank" style="color: #bc5b16;">Blog Main</a></div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=20" target="_blank"><small><em>Articles for Everyone</em></small></a>    
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=8" target="_blank"><small><em>Access to Justice Commentary</em></small></a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=5" target="_blank"><small><em>Law Commentary</em></small></a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=6" target="_blank"><small><em>Legal Futurism</em></small></a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=4" target="_blank"><small><em>Resources for Lawyers</em></small></a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=36" target="_blank"><small><em>Technology</em></small></a>              
                </div>
            </div>
          </li>
```

And the entire navbar looks like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm fixed-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home">Brandon D. Hastings<small class="hidden-md-down"> BBA(Dist.), JD</small></a>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#law">Law</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#technology">Technology</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#media">Media</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink_more" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">More</a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink_more">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#miscinfo">More About Me</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <div class="dropdown-header"><em>New Tab / Window</em></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://(bitly not allowed)/BHastings_CV" target="_blank">Curriculum Vitae</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog/category/resources-for-lawyers/" target="_blank">Resources for Lawyers</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a href="http://www.bhastings.com/blog" target="_blank" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="dropdownMenuLink_blog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown for Blog Links</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink_blog">
                  <div class="dropdown-header">Categories | <a href="http://bhastings.com/blog" target="_blank" style="color: #bc5b16;">Blog Main</a></div>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=20" target="_blank"><small><em>Articles for Everyone</em></small></a>    
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=8" target="_blank"><small><em>Access to Justice Commentary</em></small></a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=5" target="_blank"><small><em>Law Commentary</em></small></a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=6" target="_blank"><small><em>Legal Futurism</em></small></a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=4" target="_blank"><small><em>Resources for Lawyers</em></small></a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=36" target="_blank"><small><em>Technology</em></small></a>              
            </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item btn btn-danger btn-sm">
        <a class="nav-link text-white url-firm" href="http://www.quaylawcentre.com/Lawyer-Profiles/Brandon-Hastings-B-b-a-dist-j-d.shtml" target="_blank">Get in Touch<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The result is something like this in small screens:
[image]

Having a split link in a navbar is a bit hacky to begin with, but notwithstanding that, I'm wondering if anyone knows a way to get the dropdown to pop back "in line" so that it looks more like the "More" dropdown:

[image]?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `container` class in the btn-group div.
The misalignment is because of the btn-group class is defined as flex item. Try adding `container` class, it may solve the issue.

```html
    <div class="container p-0 btn-group">
       <a href="http://www.bhastings.com/blog" target="_blank" class="nav-link">Blog</a>
       <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="dropdownMenuLink_blog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown for Blog Links</span>
       </a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink_blog">
          <div class="dropdown-header">Categories | <a href="http://bhastings.com/blog" target="_blank" style="color: #bc5b16;">Blog Main</a></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=20" target="_blank"><small><em>Articles for Everyone</em></small></a>    
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=8" target="_blank"><small><em>Access to Justice Commentary</em></small></a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=5" target="_blank"><small><em>Law Commentary</em></small></a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=6" target="_blank"><small><em>Legal Futurism</em></small></a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=4" target="_blank"><small><em>Resources for Lawyers</em></small></a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://bhastings.com/blog?cat=36" target="_blank"><small><em>Technology</em></small></a>              
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**The HTML below works when you expand a collapsed navbar!**

Bootstrap: 5.0.0-beta2

```html
<li class="nav-item col-6 col-md-auto">

    <!-- NOTE: d-table on the group and nav-link d-inline for the inner <a> tags is a must for split button to work properly when collapsed/expanded -->
    <div class="btn-group d-table nav-link p-2">
        <a class="nav-link d-inline">Dropdown link</a>
        <a class="nav-link d-inline" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="far fa-caret-square-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>                                
    </div>

</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this isn't a very clean answer but I added some margin and it does the job. But can't wait to see a better solution.

```css
@media (max-width: 992px) { 
   .dropdown-menu {
        margin:35px 0 0 -150px;
   }
}
```