# How to make Bootstrap split button dropdown look like a standard dropdown in a collapsed navbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make a navbar that includes a split dropdown button, but it either looks wrong when the screen is narrow and the navbar collapses behind the toggle or it looks wrong when the screen is wide and the navbar is not collapsed.

I'm using Bootstrap 5.0.2.

I found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66615795/7484693) to add the `d-table` class to the button group, and it looks good when in the vertical mode but not in the horizontal mode, like so:

[image: Collapsed navbar with d-table]

[image: Wide navbar with d-table]

If I don't have the d-table class in the button group, it looks weird in the vertical mode and fine in the horizontal mode, like this:

[image: Collapsed navbar without d-table]

[image: Wide navbar without d-table]

For reference, I'd like it to look like this on small screens, just with the split button:

[image: Standard dropdown in collapsed navbar]

One potential solution could be to use Javascript to add/remove the d-table class depending on the screen width, but I'd like to avoid having to hardcode a screen-width value. If there is some way to detect when the navbar collapses, that would also work.

Here's the code that I used for this example:

CSS:

```
.dropdown-toggle-split {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle-split::before {
    background: #444444;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    bottom: 25%;
    height: 50%;
    width: 1px;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.dropdown-toggle-split {
    padding-left: .5rem !important;
}

.dropdown-link {
    padding-right: .5rem !important;
}

main > .container {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
<head>
    <!-- Meta -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
          crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Page -->
    <title>Split Button Dropdown</title>
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light ap-bg-light fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
                TEST
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <div class="btn-group d-table"> <!-- This is the d-table class that I've been adding/removing -->
                            <a class="nav-link d-inline active dropdown-link"
                               href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Clickable link</a>
                            <div class="nav-link d-inline active dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split"
                                 id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                                 aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                            </div>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    List item</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item"
                                       href="#">
                                    List item</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item"
                                       href="#">
                                    List item</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item"
                                       href="#">
                                    List item</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                                    List item</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li> <!-- nav-item dropdown -->
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active"
                           href="#">Another link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active"
                           href="#">Final link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Search box -->
                <form class="d-flex search">
                    <input class="form-control me-2 term" type="search" placeholder="Search"
                           aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">
                        Search
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>

<!-- Page content -->
<main class="flex-shrink-0">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</main>

<!-- JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone has any suggestions or knows of an existing answer, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know if this is the best solution but I came up with something that works. I added the following Javascript that detects when the navbar collapses and updates the DOM:

```
function checkNavBar() {
    let dropdownWrapper = $('#dropdownWrapper')
    if ($('#navToggle').is(':visible')) {
        dropdownWrapper.addClass("d-table");
    } else {
        dropdownWrapper.removeClass("d-table");
    }
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    checkNavBar();
})

$(window).ready(function () {
    checkNavBar();
})
```

The first function uses the JQuery `is()` function to test if the navbar toggle button is visible, and that function is called whenever the window is resized and when the page loads.

To make the dropdown menu expand to the full width, I added some CSS that selects only the button group that is a child of a shown `.navbar-collapse`:

```
.navbar-collapse.show .btn-group {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Not the most elegant solution in the world but it seems to work.